# What happened to the D&D power cards?

Tags: dnd-4e

I am running a party of 5 (+ me,  the DM) and have found the power cards included in the Starter Box to be really helpful to players without an iPad or something similar at hand. The power cards I have found on Amazon are overpriced ($100 for the Wizard's cards!!!).

**Has Wizards discontinued these cards?**

Comment: Hi vrinek. Welcome to the site and excellent first question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**They've been discontinued because they're not customizable. Use the online character builder or power2ool.com to generate printable cards. For electronic cards, i4e on the iPhone or iplay4e for mobile browser provide excellent experiences.**

The experiment of mass-produced power cards is considered to have failed when contrasted with customized power cards offered by various services. Therefore Wizards offers custom power cards via the [character builder](http://wizards.com/dnd/Tool.aspx?x=dnd/4new/tool/characterbuilder). While there are no official notifications, the new CB and the different focus on D&D Essentials and online Dragon made the utility of mass-printed power cards problematic.

Other sites, especially [power2ool.com](http://power2ool.com) offer similar services without the character-building capability. I use power2ool in the RPG.SE game and am quite happy with it as both player and GM.

Given that you're looking for smartphone experience, for those with iphones I can recommend i4e. It is an excellent phone-based system (one that I use personally when playing) and developed by someone who is responsive to customer feedback (I gave him rather a lot). For 'droids, I'm less sure, but the iplay4e mobile experience isn't bad if you have a fast phone. (My Iphone 3g doesn't like it all that much.) The other downside to iplay4e is that it really does want you to have a .dnd4e sheet built by the character builder. i4e allows you to enter everything by hand, which as a pedagogic technique is quite effective.

Answer (score 13):

I was inspired by [Ben's RPG Pile's post on building character decks](http://bensrpgpile.com/2010/10/21/how-to-make-a-dd-character-deck/)...

For the Power, Item, and other rule-summary cards, I use the [Magic Set Editor](http://magicseteditor.sourceforge.net/) (free) and [Tintagel's Template](http://4e.educatedgamer.net/powercards) ($9.99). To make cards that look like this:
[image: MSE Power Card using]

It does take extra work every time my party levels or gains a new enhancement-bonus related magic item (I hand transcribe the Character-Builder generated cards to this template), but then they never need the rule books!

I also print character-custom backs (or use [Paizo item cards](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/accessories/cards/itemCards) for backs - as shown with the Club card in the picture below.) Slip them both into a sleeve and behold:

[image: Item and Encounter cards]

[image: Special, Character Back, Item Graphic as Back, and Quest cards]

Comment: Awesome, and thanks for sharing your pictures!

Comment: I love creating cards for story-items the best. The flavor text will read "This spyglass is etched with the markings of The Even Keel, sunk off the coast of Coyomi. We found it amongst the wreckage."

Comment: I've also found it very useful for story items, especially when I want the players to track who has it (so I can steal it!), but my cards aren't nearly as nice.

Comment: @F.RandallFarmer, Where did you get the "Club" item card? I bought Tintagel's Templates for abilities, and it's awesome, but I don't see a template like the item card.

Comment: @William'MindWorX'Mariager - I updated the answer with a clarification and a link to the item cards I slip into the backs of important item power-cards.

Answer (score 9):

Given that power cards were effectively obsoleted by Essentials and can only be purchased second-hand, it appears they are discontinued and out of print.

Answer (score 7):

There are sites like [godeckyourself](http://www.godeckyourself.com/home.seam) where you can create your own cards. I print them out on a colour ink jet and then laminate them.